# Modifying a map object parameter for ArcGIS JavaScript API printTask?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I want to change the extent and operational layers of a map for several printTasks. The goal is to take a group of polygons, and create a map of each one separately, changing the basemap and some operational layers on each map. The resulting maps will end up in a report. What is the best approach to do this? A couple thoughts I had:

1. Change the map object to the desired operational layers and extent before printing, then revert the map object back to the original state after printing. (seems like a lot of extra steps this way)
2. Use a modified `Web_Map_as_JSON` parameter for each map. I could have this is a pre-configured string that would be easily modified. If this is a reasonable solution, is it possible to add Web_Map_as_JSON` as a parameter to the printtask like this:

   ```
       //pre-configured JSON map string
       var web_map_as_json = this.web_map_as_json

       //modify JSON here (extent of each polygon, etc..)

       var params = {
           Web_Map_as_JSON: web_map_as_json,
           Format: 'png32',
           Layout_Template: 'MAP_ONLY'
       };

       printTask.execute(params, lang.hitch(this, 'onParcelPrintComplete'), lang.hitch(this, 'onParcelPrintError'));
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for my needs:

```
      var printMapDiv = domConstruct.create('div', {id: 'printMapDiv', style: 'display: none'});

      var printMap = new Map(printMapDiv, {
            //map params
       });


      //execute print task


      //destroy the dom when you are done with the print
      domConstruct.destroy('printMapDiv');
```